# How to lock a Collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in my database

1.I want to lock my collection when the User Updating the Document

2.No operations are Done **Expect Reads** while Updating the collection for another Users

please give suggestions how to Lock the collection in MongoDB

Best Regards

GSY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB locking already does that for you. See [what operations acquire which lock](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#which-operations-lock-the-database) and [what does each lock mean](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#what-type-of-locking-does-mongodb-use).

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB implements a writer greedy database level lock already.

This means that when a specific document is being written to:

- The `User` collection would be locked
- No reads will be available until the data is written

The reason that no reads are available is because MongoDB cannot do a consistent read while writing (darn you physics, you win again).

It is good to note that if you wish for a more complex lock, spanning multiple rows, then this will not be available in MongoDB and there is no real way of implementing such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

See the MongoDB documentation on [write operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations/#write-concern?pageVersion=%5b%2761%27%5d) paying special attention to this section:

> Isolation of Write Operations
>
> The modification of a single document is always atomic, even if the write operation modifies >multiple sub-documents within that document. For write operations that modify multiple >documents, the operation as a whole is not atomic, and other operations may interleave.
>
> No other operations are atomic. You can, however, attempt to isolate a write operation that >affects multiple documents using the isolation operator.
>
> To isolate a sequence of write operations from other read and write operations, see Perform >Two Phase Commits.

Answer (score 0):

I read the mongo documentation but I couldn't find anything easy to use and mantain for my project, so I got this idea which is actually working pretty good and it's super simple and easy to use.

- First you define a Lock model where the _id is the name of the collection

  ```
   import pkg from 'mongoose';                                         
   const {Schema, model} = pkg;                                        
   const lockSchema = new Schema(
   {
       _id: {
           type: String,
           required: true
       },
       isLocked: {
           type: Boolean,
           required: true
       }
   },
   {timestamps: true}                                               
   );                                                                 
   export const Lock = model('Lock', lockSchema, 'locks');
  ```
- Then you define a middleware when you can check if the interested collection is locked (in this case you just return an error, but you could store the request in a queue so that when the collection is no more locked you process the request)

  ```
   import {Lock} from "../models/Lock.js";                            

   export const USERS_COLLECTION= 'users';                   

   export const lock = async (req, res, next) => {                     

   const {isLocked} = await Lock.findById(USERS_COLLECTION);   
   if (isLocked) {
       return res.status(409).send('operation not available for possible 
   conflict states, retry in a few seconds'); }                                                                   

   next();                                                                 
   }
  ```
- Finally in your router function, when you have multiple read and write operations with concurrency issue you **lock the collection before the first IO operation** and you **unlock the collection just before you send back the response or in case of error in the catch block**

  ```
  router.post('/users', lock, (req, res) => {                                   

  try{                                                                    
      await Lock.findByIdAndUpdate(USERS_COLLECTION, {isLocked: true});

       // multiple read/write operations on user collection                                                                                                                           

      await Lock.findByIdAndUpdate(USERS_COLLECTION, {isLocked: false});                                                                    
      res.send();                                                                                                                   
    }                                                               

  catch {                                                                                                                             
      await Lock.findByIdAndUpdate(USERS_COLLECTION, {isLocked: false});                                                   

      res.status(500).send();                                                                    
    }                                                          

  })
  ```